# How to use joinedload/contains_eager for query-enabled relationships (lazy='dynamic' option) in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following model classes declared by SQLAlchemy:

```
class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    created_at = Colmn(DateTime, nullable=False, default=func.now())

class Post(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id), nullable=False)
    user = relationship(User, backref=backref('posts', lazy='dynamic'))
    title = Column(String, nullable=False)
    body = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    created_at = Colmn(DateTime, nullable=False, default=func.now())
```

As I quoted, these models have a relationship and its backref named `posts` set to be query-enabled (through `lazy='dynamic'` option). Because some users may have the large set of posts while most users don’t.

With these models, I tried `joinedload` for `User.posts`, but I faced the error:

```
>>> users = session.query(User).options(joinedload(User.posts))[:30]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
InvalidRequestError: 'User.posts' does not support object population - eager loading cannot be applied.
```

Is there any way to work around this situation? I need following two functionalities both:

- Sometimes `User.posts` can be sliced to avoid eagerloading of the large set of posts written by heavy users.
- However usually `User.posts` should don’t produce 1+N queries.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that the property on `User` for posts is a dynamic relationship;  It's supposed to return a `Query` object.  There's no way for the property to know, or safely communicate, that this time, all of the related items are already loaded.

The simple workaround will be to have two properties, one that uses the normal lazy loading behavior (that you can set to eager load for specific queries where it makes sense), and another that always returns a dynamic relationship.

```
class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    created_at = Colmn(DateTime, nullable=False, default=func.now())

class Post(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id), nullable=False)
    user = relationship(User, backref=backref('posts'))
    title = Column(String, nullable=False)
    body = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    created_at = Colmn(DateTime, nullable=False, default=func.now())

User.post_query = relationship(Post, lazy="dynamic")
```

Comment: in my case by default I want to make `joinedload`, by exception normal lazy loading. Is it possible?

Comment: @noisy,  it is possible, but thats not too similar to this question.  [Please ask a new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Note that if you use multiple relationships like this in a many-to-many configuration, you need to mark one of the relationships as `passive_deletes=True`, otherwise a `StaleDataError` is thrown because the ORM tries to delete items in the same table through both relationships. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17242712/1255482