# SQLAlchemy DELETE Error caused by having a both lazy-load AND a dynamic version of the same relationship

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Here is some example code:

```
users_groups = Table('users_groups', Model.metadata,
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id')),
    Column('group_id', Integer, ForeignKey('groups.id'))
)

class User(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class Group(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    users = relationship('User', secondary=users_groups, lazy='select', backref='groups')
    users_dynamic = relationship('User', secondary=users_groups, lazy='dynamic')
```

So what happens here is that if you add a bunch of users to a group like so:

```
g = Group()
g.users = [User(), User(), User()]
session.add(g)
session.commit()
```

and then try to delete the group

```
session.delete(g)
session.commit()
```

You will get some form of this error:

```
DELETE statement on table 'users_groups' expected to delete 3 row(s); Only 0 were matched.
```

Removing the 2nd version of the relationship (the dynamic one in my case) fixes this problem. I am not even sure where to begin in terms of understanding why this is happening. I have been using 2 versions of various relationships in many cases throughout my SQLAlchemy models in order to make it easy to use the most appropriate query-strategy given a situation. This is the first time it has caused an unexpected issue.

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

both the Group.users and Group.users_dynamic relationships are attempting to reconcile the fact that the Group is being deleted along with being able to manage the `User()` objects they refer to; one relationship succeeds while the second one fails, as the rows in the association table were already deleted.  The most straightforward solution is to mark all but one of the identical relationships as viewonly:

```
class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    users = relationship('User', secondary=users_groups, lazy='select', backref='groups')
    users_dynamic = relationship('User', viewonly=True, secondary=users_groups, lazy='dynamic')
```

if you're still wanting to have both relationships handle some degree of mutations, you'd need to do this carefully as SQLAlchemy doesn't know how to coordinate among changes in two relationships at the same time, so conflicts like this can continue to happen (like double inserts, etc) if you make equivalent mutations on both relationships.   To just take care of the "delete" issue by itself, you can also try setting Group.users_dynamic to passive_deletes=True:

```
class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    users = relationship('User', secondary=users_groups, lazy='select', backref='groups')
    users_dynamic = relationship('User', passive_deletes=True, secondary=users_groups, lazy='dynamic')
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, adding the passive delete flag will simply prevent the ORM from attempting to delete that particular collection when the Group is deleted? If so, that seems like the most side-effect free solution, thank you.

Comment: On another note, SQLAlchemy is the best ORM I have ever used and is one of the best open source python libraries in the community, IMO. So thank you, you and your cat are awesome.

Comment: I believe I have similar code but it does not work for me... "DELETE statement on table '...association' expected to delete 2 row(s); Only 0 were matched."

Comment: Added viewonly on second(alternative) relationship and it works. Saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

I just add another simple workaround.

You can delete the collections before deleting the item itself:

```
>>> for user in group.users:
        group.users.remove(user)
>>> db.session.delete(group)
>>> db.session.commit()
```

Alternatively, you can also set it as an empty list:

```
>>> group.users = []
>>> db.session.commit()
>>> db.session.delete(group)
>>> db.session.commit()
```