# SQLAlchemy cascade delete on multiple many-to-many relationships

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

What are the proper way to define a deletion cascade on many-to-many relationship.

Trying to achieve a setup where a deletion of a user **only** deletes the the **user** and the relationship stored in **'user_favorited'**.

*The different scenarios led that the user + relationship and user favorited/favorited_by where deleted*.

Adding to the complexity are following parameters which can be added to the *relationship* and *backref*.

- single_parent
- viewonly ([stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198595/sqlalchemy-delete-error-caused-by-having-a-both-lazy-load-and-a-dynamic-version))

**Goal:**
deletion of a first user should not lead to deletion of second user favorited/favorited by. Only First user and relationship(s) should be deleted.

```
    class User(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'user'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        username = Column(String(30), nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)

        favorites = relationship("User", secondary='user_favorited',
            primaryjoin=UserFavorited.user_id==id,
            secondaryjoin=UserFavorited.favorite_user_id==id,
            backref=backref('favorites_list', lazy='dynamic', cascade='all,delete-orphan'),
            cascade="all",
            order_by=UserFavorited.favorited_on.desc())

        favorited_by = relationship("User", secondary='user_favorited',
            primaryjoin=UserFavorited.favorite_user_id==id,
            secondaryjoin=UserFavorited.user_id==id,
            backref=backref('favorited_list', lazy='dynamic', cascade='all,delete-orphan'),
            cascade="all",
            order_by=UserFavorited.favorited_on.desc())


   class UserFavorited(Base):
       __tablename__ = 'user_favorited'
       user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
       favorite_user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True, index=True)
       favorited_on = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False)
```