# How to get Flask-SQLAlchemy object to load relationship children for Jinja template?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I have basic models for User and Post. In my User model, I have

```
posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')
```

However, when I do something like

```
return render_template('user.html', users=users)
```

I want to do stuff like

```
{% for user in users %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.posts|length }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Posts is a query, not an object b/c of `lazy='dynamic'`. I can do the above if I change `lazy='joined'`, but then it would be loading all posts for users anytime I query for a User.

I tried adding `.options(joinedload('posts'))` to my query, but it said that

> InvalidRequestError: 'User.posts' does not support object population - eager loading cannot be applied.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply remove the `lazy="dynamic"` argument and you will be able to use a `joinedload` without issues.  (Remember, when you do this you open yourself up to hard-to-diagnose N+1 query issues.  If you will always need the posts, use `joined` instead).

If you need all behaviors (queriable, joinable, and lazy-loaded), I suggest looking at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935809/how-to-use-joinedload-contains-eager-for-query-enabled-relationships-lazy-dyna), which suggests adding another attribute for dynamic queries:

```
class User(db.Model):
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='user')

class Post(db.Model):
    # etc.

User.posts_query = db.relationship(Post, lazy='dynamic')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a [query object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#the-query-object) yes, but those query objects have methods which might help you. Specifically for this use case, you can do:

```
{% for user in users %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.posts.count() }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This will result in `N+1` queries (where `1` gets the users and `N` is the number of users that are returned) because `count` will go and fetch the total number of posts for this user from the database for each user.

Comment: @SeanVieira If I just need to count the items, I better use default lazy (i.e. `select`), then use Jinja's `length` to get the count in the template, instead of using`lzay='dynamic'` with `count()`?

Comment: You're actually far better off using a separate query completely if all you need is `User, post count` - if you're going to use all the posts in rendering the template then yes `| length` is what you'd want instead of issuing a `count` for every user.

Answer (score -1):

You must perform .first() or .all() to your query object to get the actual object/list. 
e.g
`users = User.query.all()`