# SQLAlchemy - add count property to model class

Tags: sqlalchemy, relationship, flask-sqlalchemy

If I have a class model with a lazy relationship:

```
class Products(db.Model):
    # (...) columns

    colors = db.Relationship('Colors', 
        back_populates='product',
        lazy = 'dynamic')
```

How would I go about creating an extra property for this class which I could access as:

```
product = Products.query.first()
number_of_colors = product.num_colors
```

Any ideas?
BTW, it is a Flask project, and the above is just a simplified example of what I am trying to achieve. Please let me know if you need more info.

Thanks!!

Comment: After trying a different search term, I get this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019567/how-to-get-flask-sqlalchemy-object-to-load-relationship-children-for-jinja-templ which is quite similar to what I need... But it would be great to get this as a property, as in my question, because I do need a lazy relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for sqlalchemy hybrid properties.

```
@hybrib_property
def num_colors(self)
    return len(self.colors)
```

Comment: thanks, I'll look into that and get back here with results!