# Query returning every cover in db for each entry?

Tags: database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

My query seems to be returning 1 entry for each cover. That is, if I have 3 covers in the database, then the query will return entry #1 three times with each of the different covers. Since I have 7 entries, I'm getting 21 results. How do I structure my query to return the cover associated with the entry?

Here's what I have:

```
@app.route('/list', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def list():
    entries = Book.query.order_by(Book.id.desc()).all()
    cvr_entries = Cover.query.filter(Cover.book).all()

    ### Other queries I've tried ###

    # cvr_entries = Cover.query.join(Cover.book).all()
    # cvr_entries = Cover.query.filter(Cover.book.any())
    # cvr_entries = Cover.query.filter(Cover.book.any()).all()

    return render_template(
        'list.html',
        entries=entries,
        cvr_entries=cvr_entries)
```

Here's the `/list` output page:

```
{% for entry in entries %}
{% for cvr in cvr_entries %}

<article class="entry">
    <img src="/static/data/covers/{{ cvr.name }}" alt="Cover for {{ entry.title }}" />
    <ul class="entry-info">
        <li class=""><h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2></li>
        <li class="">Summary: {{ entry.summary|truncate( 30, true ) }}</li>
    </ul>
</article>

{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Switching the order of the `entries` and `cvr_entries` `for` loops changes nothing. I've also tried adding `first()` instead of `all()`, but that leads to an error where it says

```
TypeError: 'Cover' object is not iterable
```

so that was a bust. I don't understand how to build the query.

Here is my model, as requested by @jonafato:

```
book_to_cover = db.Table('book_to_cover',
    db.Column('cover_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cover.id')),
    db.Column('book_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('book.id'))
)

class Book(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'book'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String())
    summary = db.Column(db.Text)

    book_to_cover = db.relationship('Cover', secondary=book_to_cover,
        backref=db.backref('book', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Book (title='%s')>" % (self.title)


class Cover(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cover'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Cover (name='%s')>" % self.name
```

Comment: Can you post your SQLAlchemy models? In particular, do you have a relationship defined between `Book` and `Cover` (with a backref)? If so, you should be able to remove `cvr_entries` query entirely and change your inner `for` loop to be something like `{% for cvr in entry.covers %}`.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, you can use a [`joinedload`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#joined-load) to prevent unnecessary queries inside of the loop.

Comment: @jonafato I tried `cvr_entries = Cover.query.options(joinedload(Cover.book))`, but I got `NameError: global name 'joinedload' is not defined`. I also tried the `entry.covers` approach, but no entries were returned at all.

Comment: You have to import `joinedload` from `sqlalchemy.orm` before you can use it.

Comment: I imported it and got the error `InvalidRequestError: 'Cover.book' does not support object population - eager loading cannot be applied.` I found a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935809/how-to-use-joinedload-contains-eager-for-query-enabled-relationships-lazy-dyna), but that didn't work. I also changed my loading from `dynamic` to `joined` to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you iterate over the model-- your relationships should allow you to do:

```
books = Book.query.all()
return render_template('list.html', books=books)
```

Then in your Jinja2 `list.html` template:

```
{% for book in books %}
    <h3>{{ book }}</h3>
    <ul>
    {% for cover in book.book_to_cover %}
        <li>{{ cover }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

It'd be more natural to rename the `book_to_cover` to `covers` to make it more like natural language when you access the model.